# PostgreSQL recursive function returns set of record

Tags: postgresql, recursion, sql-function

I am writing a PostgreSQL recursive function which returns a set of records, but I do not know the correct syntax of it. The recursive table here is Vertical which contains below columns:

```
CREATE TABLE vertical
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  insert_timestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  deleted smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  parent_id integer, // refer to another Vertical
  locations character varying(200),
  level smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  CONSTRAINT vertical_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT vertical_parent_fkey FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
      REFERENCES vertical (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT name_ukey UNIQUE (name )
)
```

Here is my SQL statement (get all childs of a Vertical by specified id):

```
CREATE FUNCTION getAllVerticalChilds(verticalId integer) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
   WITH RECURSIVE childs(id, name, parent_id, level) AS (
   SELECT child.id, child.name, child.parent_id, child.level
   FROM vertical child
   WHERE child.parent_id = verticalId
   UNION ALL
   SELECT parent.id, parent.name, parent.parent_id, parent.level
   FROM childs child
   INNER JOIN vertical parent ON parent.parent_id = child.id where parent.deleted=0
   )
   SELECT id, name, parent_id, level
   FROM childs;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Could you please help me correct this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In postgresql you have to use statement RETURN if you can push some from function. In your case probably RETURN QUERY ...

```
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY WITH RECURSIVE ...
END
```

and a usage of your function will be much more user friendly if you declare your function as TABLE function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xx(..) RETURNS TABLE(a int, b int, ...)
```

a usage of this function is (PostgreSQL has not statement CALL)

```
SELECT * FROM xx(..)
```